# Can't get trigger to run

Tags: mysql, triggers

Please pardon my ignorance if this is a dumb question but I'm trying to create a trigger that will set a column in my table to a randomly generated number between 2-7. This is the code I've come up with so far...

```
    delimiter go
    create trigger BillerCodeSelect BEFORE INSERT on time_sheets for each row
    begin
    Set ASSIGNEE_CODE = floor(2+rand()*7);
    end
    go
    delimiter ;
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be
>   used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.

I have verified that I am using the correct table name. Anything pop out as completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the right panel, right click on the Database and click on 'Set As Default Schema`

Comment: Thanks... that was the issue. Had to fix some other syntax issues but that got it to take the trigger. Thank you again.